# Django queryset - query the first day every two years with the equivalent price

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following fee_table holding date and price on a daily basis.

[fee_talbe -- date and price on a daily basis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj0az.png)

What is the most efficient way to query the first day every two years with the equivalent price without using raw SQL queries ?

for example:

```
{'date': 2002-01-01, 'price': 100}
{'date': 2004-01-01, 'price': 124.6}
{'date': 2006-01-01, 'price': 131.9}
```

Comment: what do you mean by every second year?

Comment: {'date': 2002-01-01, 'price': 100}
{'date': 2004-01-01, 'price': 124.6}
{'date': 2006-01-01, 'price': 131.9}

Comment: You meant every two years starting from a specific year. or it could be `even` year

Comment: from a specific date, every product start being sold from different date..